# Need to have Expanded in TabBarView but error with height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to have a `TabBarView` with a `Expanded` widget. `TabBarView` is between widgets. Works with `Sizedbox` with height.

Errors like

> Failed assertion: line 1651 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true
>
> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#3caee relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>
> Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'

`TabBarView` is at the end of the code:

```
class TabBarNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  TabBarNavigation({this.posts});
  final List<Post> posts;

  @override
  _TabBarNavigationState createState() => _TabBarNavigationState();
}

class _TabBarNavigationState extends State<TabBarNavigation>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      initialIndex: 0,
      child: Padding(
        padding: kPaddingTabBar,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: kLightGrey,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(50),
                ),
              ),
              child: TabBar(
                tabs: <Tab>[Tab(text: kArtwork), Tab(text: kPastJobs)],
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black54,
                labelColor: Colors.black,
                unselectedLabelStyle: kBoldText,
                labelStyle: kBoldText,
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                indicator: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: kCommonSeparation),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: _tabController,
                children: [ArtworkTab(widget.posts), PastJobsTab()]
              )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception say: "Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize". I Think that it's happen why TabBarView need const size, I suggest you Wrap with a Container tag with fixed height, not a Expanded.
Sorry about my english.

This type of exception happen when some assert method fails, so, I thing it could be useful to understand the exception: https://www.w3adda.com/dart-tutorial/dart-assert-statement

I suggest you change your code to something like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      initialIndex: 0,
      child: Padding(
        padding: kPaddingTabBar,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: kLightGrey,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(50),
                ),
              ),
              child: TabBar(
                tabs: <Tab>[Tab(text: kArtwork), Tab(text: kPastJobs)],
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black54,
                labelColor: Colors.black,
                unselectedLabelStyle: kBoldText,
                labelStyle: kBoldText,
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                indicator: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: kCommonSeparation),
            Container(
              height: 200,
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: _tabController,
                children: [ArtworkTab(widget.posts), PastJobsTab()]
              )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

So, I make a quick widget to solve this problem, be free to use:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomEasyTabBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Tab> tabs;
  final List<Widget> pages;
  CustomEasyTabBar({
    @required this.tabs,
    @required this.pages,
  }) {
    assert(tabs != null && pages != null);
    assert(tabs.length == pages.length);
  }
  @override
  _CustomEasyTabBarState createState() => _CustomEasyTabBarState();
}

class _CustomEasyTabBarState extends State<CustomEasyTabBar>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController tabController;
  int currentTabIndex = 0;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.tabController = TabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: this.widget.tabs.length,
      vsync: this,
    );
    this.tabController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        this.currentTabIndex = this.tabController.index;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _builderTabs(this.widget.tabs),
        _builderPages(this.currentTabIndex, this.widget.pages),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _builderPages(int currentIndex, List<Widget> pages) {
    int localIndex = 0;
    return Column(
      children: pages.map<Widget>((e) {
        if (localIndex == currentIndex) {
          localIndex++;
          return e;
        }
        localIndex++;
        return Container();
      }).toList(),
    );
  }

  Widget _builderTabs(List<Tab> tabs) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      width: width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: CustomColors.primary),
      child: Center(
        child: TabBar(
          controller: tabController,
          indicatorWeight: 4,
          labelColor: Colors.white,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white30,
          indicatorColor: CustomColors.secondary,
          isScrollable: true,
          tabs: tabs,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the exception say it: "Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize". Happen when some assert method fails, so, I thing it could be useful to understand the exception  https://www.w3adda.com/dart-tutorial/dart-assert-statement

Comment: You can edit your answer instead of posting a comment. Please provide an actual code example if possible.

Comment: The problem is that I need an expanded widget: The idea behind the `ArtworkTab` is to print a list of posts and I don't know to do it, hope this helps if you have any idea on how to do it. I had a fixed height as a temporary fix.